# Can I bypass requirement by CMAKE to provide separate compiler and linker while making module for custom Language?

Tags: makefile, cmake, sbcl

I am trying to make a CMAKE module for generating Makefiles to compile SBCL (Steel Bank Common Lisp) project.

There is a tool to generate executable for sbcl, called Buildapp but it does not seem to involve compiling objects and linking them in to an executable as generic C/C++ programs are built.

Here is an [example for Makefile](http://www.luyanxin.com/programming/getting-ready-to-write-programs-in-common-lisp.html) that works for building a Lisp program into executable.

And here is an example of bare minimum [example to make similar task for Go](https://github.com/grmartin/clion-go-lang-cmake) language.

What seems to be the last thing missing in my "cmake Lisp language module" to implement is this piece of code in Golang example (in CMakeGoInformation.cmake):

```
if(NOT CMAKE_Go_COMPILE_OBJECT)
  set(CMAKE_Go_COMPILE_OBJECT "go tool 6g -l -N -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE> ")
endif()
if(NOT CMAKE_Go_LINK_EXECUTABLE)
  set(CMAKE_Go_LINK_EXECUTABLE "go tool 6l -o <TARGET> <OBJECTS>  ")
endif()
```

Example above does not use 'go build' that would compile and link in one step but some other compiler / linker. In my case I don't even think I need a separate compiler/linker steps and could go with simple step as in example 1.

Question is - how can I do that? 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: You may try `set(CMAKE_Go_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS lisp)`, so CMake would interpret `*.lisp` files as not required compiling, and pass them directly to linker. Similar mechanism is used for C language in [CMakeCCompiler.cmake.in](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=blob;f=Modules/CMakeCCompiler.cmake.in;h=50b12f28a2d659b8749f4e5343520873236f8241;hb=HEAD)

Comment: Technically I don't need a two step build process at all. But I think I got what CMake means with <SOURCE> <OBJECT> and <TARGET>. <SOURCE> seems to be an original source where project and related CMakeLists.txt is and <OBJECT> is that stuff that is collected in a build_dir/CMakeFiles/target.dir/. Then CMake will call "linker" to process everything in target.dir to make <TARGET> ... I guess ... ? At the moment I am just doing 'cp <SOURCE> <OBJECT>' to collect all .lisp files in one place. IGNORE_EXTENSIONS does not seem to influence anything in my case.